# Python Unable to convert Unix time into ISO 8601 zulu time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code, which takes the Unix time and converts it into ISO 8601 zulu time i.e. `2022-09-16T20:25:47.649Z`

```
    if "reported_at" in event:
        reported_at = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(event.get("reported_at"))).isoformat()+"Z"
```

Where event is

```
{
  "reported_at": 1663359947649,
}
```

I am getting below error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "year 54679 is out of range",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 37, in lambda_handler\n    reported_at = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(event.get(\"reported_at\"))).isoformat()+\"Z\"\n"
  ]
}
```

Not sure what is missing I tried couple of different alterations but same error, can some please guide.

PS: I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

`1663359947649` is the number of milliseconds, not seconds since the unix epoch! Solution: Divide by a thousand.

```py
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1663359947649/1000)
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 16, 20, 25, 47, 649000)
```